# How do I fix @app.route syntax error with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

But Python is prompting the following error:

```
@app.route('/')
...
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That looks like you're trying to enter the code line-by-line in an interactive Python session, rather than typing everything into a file and then running that file.  The syntax rules are slightly different in interactive mode - you cannot enter a blank line in the middle of a multi-line statement of any sort.  Specifically, the blank line between the decorator and the function it decorates is causing the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and it worked for me. There does not seem to be a clear syntax error.

Try saving your file again and clearing your terminal before running it.

Another alternative is running the following in your command prompt before running your code:

```
set FLASK_APP={name of your file}.py
```

In the command prompt it should look something like this:

```
C:\path\to\app>set FLASK_APP=hello.py
```

Lastly, you can also try running it by writing the following in your command prompt or terminal instead of using the main() function you have now:

```
python -m flask run
```

More details and alternatives here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I closed everything, restarted and it worked afterwards.